# Using variables as value and not as reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, ref

I'm having some troubles using Session Variables as they are being used as **Reference** and I want to use them as **value**.

I got to this debuging my solution and I created something like:

```
DataTable dt = 
     (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session[
                      "SearchReturn-DataTableSchema"];

// Adding Rows of Data to DataTable dt

HttpContext.Current.Session["SearchReturn-DataTable"] = dt;

((DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session[
     "SearchReturn-DataTableSchema"]).Rows.Clear();

return dt;
```

my idea was to have in "**DataTableSchema**" only the DataTable with the Columns Schema and in "**DataTable**" the Columns + Rows.

> **Problem is** that when I clear all rows from **DataTableSchema**, the variable dt will have the Rows cleared as well (!!)

How can avoid this? How can assign a variable (in this case a Session variable) as a value and not as a reference?

Thank you.

---

> Answer

this

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["SearchReturn-DataTableSchema"];
```

needs to be this:

```
DataTable dt = ((DataTable)Session["SearchReturn-DataTableSchema"]).Copy();
```

:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to make a copy of your table.

Comment: forgot all about DataTable.Copy() :)

Answer (score 2):

An interesting part of this is that the behaviour will depend on your session-state provider. You are presumably using the in-process provider at the moment, which keeps references - but most providers (understandably) use serialization.

This often bites people when they try to scale up, as they find that they have something non-serializable in session. So you might consider pushing state into a different provider; SQL-Server, memcached, etc - they will all do serialization so the data will be independent.

Comment: The good about knowing what and how .NET handles stuff :) BTW: Are you "always" online? Don't you sleep? Work? ;-)

Comment: If you look closely at my usage, you'll see *very* clearly-defined gaps during work time (except maybe for lunch)... let's just say we "had words" about it ;-p But sleep is over-rated...

Answer (score 0):

Use the .Copy() Method of your DataTable:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also
You can Clone DataTable Schema using Clone method. 
And then Load data via Load and CreateReader methods.